# Would Iridium be a good metal for crafting muskets and cannons?

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons, chemistry, firearms

Iridium is a metal discovered in 1803 that is quite dense and is very resistant against corrosion.

Let's say that in the year 1600, every musket and cannon on Earth has their metal components magically replaced with Iridium. Would these new Iridium muskets and cannons perform better or worse compared to how they performed before this event?

Comment: Are you going to scroll through the entire periodic table with the same type of question? It should be clear by now which properties are needed for usage in medieval weapon. You are just asking us to compile the properties of each element you pick in the current permutation.

Comment: Density and corrosion-resistance aren't the only two criteria that would need to be considered: there is availability, hardness, toughness (_not_ the same thing), what alloys does it form, what are the characteristics of the alloys, melting point, ... Let us just say that metallurgy is a complex subject, and questions like this aren't really meaningful.

Comment: Density is an almost worthless property for cannons (though useful for cannonballs, to an extent). Much effort went into making guns *lighter*, not heavier.

Comment: You need to learn some chemistry, some physics, a little metallurgy, and some history of weaponry. Currently you don't know enough to ask sensible questions and are wasting your time with silly ones.

Comment: @L.Dutch, the previous posts were generally about swords and armor. This question is about muskets and cannons. Completely different tools.

Comment: In spite of being an FCC metal, it is considered very brittle.

Comment: It's irrelevant if they're "completely different tools." (They're not in the context of your questions, BTW.) You're asking pattern quesitons, again. "How does a material only available in our day benefit a tool in the past?" Asked over and over. @L.Dutch is correct, what haven't you learned from the previous iterations of these questions that you need to ask another? In the end, we do give people fish, *but the goal of Stack Exchange is to teach people how to fish.* Pattern questions suggest "mindless social fun," which is prohibited by the [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Worse**

I do not believe the hydraulic press channel has made a video where they crush a ring of Iridium. But I wager brittle is the opposite of what you want for a machine designed to withstand sudden stresses. In particular from exploding a cannonball out of it. Brittle things tend to shatter when you hit them hard and suddenly.

The cannon might still work for a few shots. Those things are pretty thick. But I imagine it will eventually crack in half and you have no more cannon.

On the other hand the cannon might survive longer underwater than a normal cannon, since it is hard to corrode. In a million years the Next Men will pull the cannon out of the sediment at the bottom of the ocean and realise why these guys all went extinct. Their iridium cannons were inferior to the other guys' iron cannons.

Answer (score 2):

It would be worse for two reasons. First is how very brittle iridium is. Unless they were all replaced with an alloy of iridium (like one with some titanium added), they would just explode when fired. The outward force of the exploding gunpowder has to be held in and directed, which it's unlikely that Iridium could do, so the people shooting them would be seriously injured. The other problem would be the density. Iridium is an extremely dense element, which would make those muskets super heavy as well. Muskets were already inaccurate, but the heavier they are the more difficult they would be to hold steady. Therefore, even if they could get a shot off without killing the user, the bullet would tend to go even further off course. If the bullets and cannon balls were also made from iridium, assuming they didn't shatter immediately, they would have a very short range because of the extreme density. that means you would have to get deep inside your enemies firing range before you would get close enough to have any chance of hitting them.